# cmake <-> make and unit testing: creating targets that don't compile unless named explicetly

Tags: c++, unit-testing, architecture, googletest

I want to structure my unit tests, using gtest, in modules. each module is often a collection of multiple testible units. whilst developing a module i create a unit test at a time, and once finished I concatinate them into one unittest for the entire module.

So for some illustration, each test looks like this.

```
// file test1.cc
TEST1()
{
}
TESTn
{
)
#ifdef ISOLATED_TEST_COMPILE
int main()
{
   /* google test boiler plate */
}
#endif
```

And a file that concatinates the test looks like this

```
#include "test1.cc"
#include "testn.cc"

int main()
{
   /* google test boiler plate */
}
```

So I wan't to be able to get the generated make build to build individual tests only when named, and to not include individual tests in the "all" target. The entire module unity unit test build should be in the all target.

I don't want `make all` to redundtly compile single tests.

Answer (score 0):

If unit tests aren't in production, the quick and dirty would be to use #ifdef the same way you did above.

Then you just simply wrap the defines for the ifdefs like so.

```
#ifdef ALL
  ...
#else
  #define UNIT1
  ....
#end if
```

Comment: the more ifdefs code has the nastier it is to read, I could script this up in cmake though

Comment: @Hassan Syed True. I was assuming that you already had ifdefs around each unit. At which point you'd only be adding one more.

Comment: actually now that I am with my code again, it isn't about the functionality about conditionally compiling stuff, it's about the abstraction of being able to say `make unit_test_name`.Your method asks me to pass a -D to the preprocessor, something along the line of `make -Dsubmodule_unit_test_name unit_test_module_name`.